# Domain of the probability density function - Change of variables formula

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, change-of-variable

I've a random variable $X$ with the following PDF:

$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\mid x \mid \, \cos(x^2) & \text{if } x \in \left[ - \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}, \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \right]  \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The goal is to evaluate the PDF of the r. v. $Y = X^2$. I applyed the change of variables' formula and I got:

$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
\cos(y) & \text{if } y??? \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I get the domain of the $f_Y(y)$?

Comment: If $x$ is between $-\sqrt{\pi/2}$ and $\sqrt{\pi/2}$, then what is $x^2$ between?

Comment: Hello @MinusOne-Twelfth it's $y \in [\pi/2, \, \pi/2]$, but it's wrong..can you tell me how to get the right result $[0, \, \pi/2]$ please? How to get the zero?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth maybe I should imagine a flip of the x axis around the zero?

Comment: Hello @MinusOne-Twelfth it's $y \in [\pi/2, \pi/2]$, but it's wrong..can you tell me how to get the right result $(0, \, \pi/2]$ please? How to get the zero?

Answer (score 1):

You have that

$$
F_Y(c)=\Pr [Y\leqslant c]=\Pr [X^2\leqslant c]=\begin{cases}
\Pr [|X|\leqslant \sqrt{c}],&c\geqslant 0\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Now, for $c\geqslant 0$ you have that

$$
\Pr [|X|\leqslant \sqrt{c}]=\Pr [X\in[-\sqrt{c},\sqrt{c}]]=\int_{-\sqrt{c}}^{\sqrt{c}}f_X(t)\,d t\\
\therefore\quad f_Y(c)=F'_Y(c)=\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{d c}\int_{-\sqrt{c}}^{\sqrt{c}}f_X(t)\,d t,&0\leqslant c\leqslant \pi/2\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
because if $c>\pi/2$ then the integral $\int_{-\sqrt{c}}^{\sqrt{c}}f_X(t)\,d t$ will be constant. Then, finally, we find that

$$
\begin{align*}
f_Y(c)&=\begin{cases}
f_X(\sqrt{c})\frac1{2\sqrt{c}}-f_X(-\sqrt{c})\frac1{-2\sqrt{c}},&0< c\leqslant \pi/2\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\cos (c),&0< c\leqslant \pi/2\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}\\
&=\mathbf{1}_{(0,\pi/2]}(c)\cos (c)
\end{align*}
$$

Note: observe that $F_Y$ is not differentiable at $c=0$, however it doesn't matter the value we choose for $f_Y$ at this point as it doesn't change the value of $F_Y$. In a measure theoretic setting we says that any $f_Y$ such that $F_Y(c)=\int_{-\infty }^c f_Y(t)\,d t$ is a density of $Y$. In general densities are classes of integrable functions, functions that are equal "almost everywhere" respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hello @Masacroso there is an error $c$ cannot be equal to zero because we have $\sqrt{c}$ at the denominator

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi right! I will edit it